# How find address of a function in a dll that is exporting this same function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dllexport

I'm have a dll file that exports a function where i will load inside another dll file.

My problem is that not is possible find function on second dll, tried do equals [this tutorial](http://www.infernodevelopment.com/simple-c-dll-loading-message-box), but nothing of success until now .

Any suggestion will welcome.

Code:

below is dll that loads a function that is exported by another dll:

Code:

below is dll that loads a function that is exported by another dll:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *TERMINATEPROCESS_PROC)(HANDLE, UINT);

TERMINATEPROCESS_PROC HookFunction(char *UserDll,TERMINATEPROCESS_PROC pfn,TERMINATEPROCESS_PROC HookFunc) 
{                    
    DWORD dwSizeofExportTable=0;
    DWORD dwRelativeVirtualAddress=0;
    HMODULE hm=GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pim=(PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hm;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pimnt=(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)pim + 
(DWORD)pim->e_lfanew); 
    PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY 
pimdata=(PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY)&(pimnt->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory);

    PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER pot=&(pimnt->OptionalHeader);
    PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY 
pim2=(PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY)((DWORD)pot+(DWORD)104);
    dwSizeofExportTable=pim2->Size;
    dwRelativeVirtualAddress=pim2->VirtualAddress;
    char *ascstr;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR 
pimexp=(PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(pim2->VirtualAddress + (DWORD)pim);
    while(pimexp->Name)
    {
        ascstr=(char *)((DWORD)pim + (DWORD)pimexp->Name);
        if(_strcmpi(ascstr,UserDll) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        pimexp++;
    }
    PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA 
pname=(PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((DWORD)pim+(DWORD)pimexp->FirstThunk);
    LPDWORD lpdw=&(pname->u1.Function);
    DWORD dwError=0;
    DWORD OldProtect=0;
    while(pname->u1.Function)
    {
        if((DWORD)pname->u1.Function == (DWORD)pfn)
        {
            lpdw=&(pname->u1.Function);

VirtualProtect((LPVOID)lpdw,sizeof(DWORD),PAGE_READWRITE,&OldProtect);


            pname->u1.Function=(DWORD)HookFunc;

VirtualProtect((LPVOID)lpdw,sizeof(DWORD),PAGE_READONLY,&OldProtect);

            return pfn;
        }
        pname++;

    }
    return (TERMINATEPROCESS_PROC)0;
}

TERMINATEPROCESS_PROC CallHook(void) 
{

    DWORD dwAddOfTerminateProcess;

    HMODULE hm=GetModuleHandle(TEXT("Kernel32.dll"));
    TERMINATEPROCESS_PROC fp=(TERMINATEPROCESS_PROC)GetProcAddress(hm,"TerminateProcess");
    HMODULE hm2=GetModuleHandle(TEXT("Math.dll"));
    TERMINATEPROCESS_PROC fpHook=(TERMINATEPROCESS_PROC)GetProcAddress(hm2,"MyTerminateProcess");

    dwAddOfTerminateProcess=(DWORD)HookFunction("Kernel32.dll",fp,fpHook);

     if(dwAddOfTerminateProcess == 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Unable TO Hook Function."),TEXT("Parth"),MB_OK);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Success Hooked."),TEXT("Parth"),MB_OK);
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
         CallHook();
       break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

here is dll that contains function to be exported:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Mathlib.h"

// a sample exported function
BOOL DLL_EXPORT MyTerminateProcess(HANDLE hProcess,UINT uExitCode)
{
     SetLastError(5);
     return FALSE;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

header.h file:

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#include <windows.h>

/*  To use this exported function of dll, include this header
 *  in your project.
 */

#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

  BOOL DLL_EXPORT MyTerminateProcess(HANDLE hProcess,UINT uExitCode);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

Comment: What's wrong with just using `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`?

Comment: @KenWhite, is returning empty when i use like this : `MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)hm2,TEXT("Parth"),MB_OK);`

Comment: I have no idea what your comment is supposed to mean (I don't know why you think you could typecast a module handle to a wide string), and it doesn't answer the question I asked. Let me try again: *What's wrong with `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`?* If `LoadLibrary()` fails, what does `GetLastError()` tell you?